# What is the function of に in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-に

> 待ち合わせ場所は名古屋市内。ショートカットの髪型**に**Ｔシャツ、デニムで来てくれたのはユウさん（仮名）、いま高校生です。([source](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20180625/k10011494911000.html?utm_int=netnewsup_contents_list-items_001))